# Path issue shows with composer installing via MAMP on macOS

Tags: php, laravel, macos, composer-php, mamp

When I have tried to install composer for laravel 8 on localhost MAMP

I have gotten this message in command line (terminal): -bash:

/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/**php7.4.16**/bin/php: No such file or directory

notice **php7.4.16** shows in path, although I'm using ver 8, further to, this version is no longer supported and not in use at all.

I had searched for solving my problem in google, until I found the following treatment for solving path issue, but it doesn't benefit me:

https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/mamp-with-composer-and-mysql-on-the-command-line

it has replaced the php ver path I have actually, but the problem is still.

why this version shows in my installation path although it's old & dead version?

what I should do?

kindly, anybody could help me to solve this problem?

Also, could me to install composer on XAMPP instead of MAMP, because I have a copy of it on my MacBook computer already?

Thank you for my helping in advance.